# How to access Outlook email by a Delphi subthread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, outlook

I use this to access Outlook emails in a subthread:

```
try
  Outlook := GetActiveOleObject('Outlook.Application') ;
except
  Outlook := CreateOleObject('Outlook.Application') ;
end;
NameSpace := Outlook.GetNameSpace('MAPI');
Folder := NameSpace.Folders;
```

After finding the specified folder I access emails in a loop by a:

```
var MailItem: Variant;
MailItem := Folder.Items[i];
```

Then I use the list of mail items in my application to access them.
This works in the main thread or in the subthread itself.
But when I pass `MailItem` obtained from a subthread to the main thread I get an excepion.
It seems that `Folder.Items` returns a pointer that is strictly assigned to the subthread and is not accesible from the main thread.

How should I get a long list of emails not to block the main thread? I want something nicer than `Application.ProcessMessages;`

Answer (score 1):

Where is your code running? Is it a standalone exe or a COM addin? Keep in mind that Outlook 2013 will raise an exception as soon as it detects that is object is being used rom a thread other than its main thread (in case of a COM addin). In case of a standalone exe, all calls are marshaled to the main Outlook thread anyway, so you are not gaining anything by using secondary threads.

You can use Extended MAPI or a MAPI wrapper (such as [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm) - I am its author) - its [RDO](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo_introduction.htm) family of object is thread safe.

Comment: It is a standalone exe but it still blocks the main thread if I try to load about 1000 emails from Outlook (2010). So I am thinking of a thread. Can you suggest how to use Extended MAPI to solve this?

Comment: I don't think a MAPI tutorial will fit here :-) It is a low level API totally different from the Outlook Object Model.

Comment: Well, what can I do then? Stay with Application.ProcessMessages... :)

Comment: You can learn Extended MAPI, but expect the learning curve to be very steep. No quick one afternoon project I am afraid... If Redemption is an option, you can use it instead of pure MAPI - its RDO family of objects is a wrapper around Extended MAPI and can be used in a secondary thread. Create an instance of the RDOSession object on the main thread, call RDOSession.Logon (or set the RDOSession.MAPIOBJECT property to Namespace.MAPIOBJECT from Outlook). On the secondary threads, create another instance of RDOSession object (to make sure MAPI is initialized), set its RDOSession.MAPIOBJECT, etc.